# How to retrieve a limited number of products from the catalog?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

I am trying to retrieve a limited number (three) of products from the catalog. Here's my (not working) code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$products->getSelect()->limit(3);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    // Do stuff with $product
}
```

The problem is I am getting sometimes only one product and sometimes no products. Although I have more than three products in the catalog.

**Edit:**

Here is the query computed by `$products->getSelect();`:

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `miiny_catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ORDER BY rand() ASC LIMIT 3
```

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4.

Thanks in advance.

Louis.

Comment: This code is correct, it should always return 3 random items from the collection.

Comment: I thought it was. Anyway this does not render the result I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to search for an error somewhere else. Is there anything appearing in the logs/apache logs when less than 3 products are returned?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productsCollection
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productsCollection
         ->getSelect()
         ->order('rand()');
$products = $productsCollection
         ->setPageSize(3)
         ->setCurPage(1)
         ->load();
```

what you recive error?
try look log

`tailf -100 var/log/system.log`

`tailf -100 var/log/exception.log`

in magento for get more information, about error.

and you can enable error for display on develop server by local.xml in directory errors.

`cp errors/local.xml.simple errors/local.xml`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm getting the same result (only one product or no products). `tail -f -100 var/log/system.log` returns `2016-07-06T12:50:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: addcslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given  in /Users/louisfischer/Projects/miiny/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 296`. Also I get every product when removing `$products->getSelect()->limit(3);` or `$products = $productsCollection->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1)->load();`

Comment: you can look you query by `echo $productsCollection->getSelect()`  and please post you query in qwession

Comment: `SELECT \`e\`.*, \`price_index\`.\`price\`, \`price_index\`.\`tax_class_id\`, \`price_index\`.\`final_price\`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS \`minimal_price\`, \`price_index\`.\`min_price\`, \`price_index\`.\`max_price\`, \`price_index\`.\`tier_price\` FROM \`miiny_catalog_product_entity\` AS \`e\` INNER JOIN \`miiny_catalog_product_index_price\` AS \`price_index\` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 ORDER BY rand() ASC LIMIT 3`.